# Convert A dataframe to a dictionary with custom structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, format

**I have the following data frame:**

```
             3        10          6          4           timestamp
462  75.768780  21.47490  20.725380  100.00000 2020-04-08 08:30:05
463  77.612500  21.47490  21.025310  100.00000 2020-04-08 08:30:35
464  77.612500  18.41914  21.025310  100.00000 2020-04-08 08:30:40
465  75.851290  18.41914  19.776660  100.00000 2020-04-08 08:31:05
466   2.908084  16.36317   4.460456    4.48286 2020-04-08 08:31:25
```

**I want to convert this into a format like below if the df contains a time stamp column:**

```
{datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 8, 8, 30, 5, tzinfo=<UTC>): {'3': 75.76878,
  '10': 21.474900000000005,
  '6': 20.72538,
  '4': 100.0},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 8, 8, 30, 35, tzinfo=<UTC>): {'3': 77.6125,
  '10': 21.474900000000005,
  '6': 21.02531,
  '4': 100.0},
}
```

**If the data frame is in the format without timestamp column:**

```
       1       2                  3
36026  7.2246  5.4106             0.0
36027  7.2154  5.4115             0.0
36028  7.1923  5.4111             0.0
36029  7.2028  5.4106             0.0
36030  7.2141  5.4123             0.0
```

**I want to convert this data frame into a format like below:**

```
{36026: {'1': 7.2246, '2': 5.4106, '3': 0.0},
 36027: {'1': 7.2154, '2': 5.4115, '3': 0.0},
 36028: {'1': 7.1923, '2': 5.4111, '3': 0.0},
 36029: {'1': 7.2028, '2': 5.4106, '3': 0.0},
 36030: {'1': 7.2141, '2': 5.4123, '3': 0.0}}
```

Currently what I am trying to achieve this using `df.iterrows()` in a for loop and then converting it to the corresponding format.

Any Efficient solution would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: `df.to_dict("index")`, it should work for your second dataframe

Comment: For the second df, it Worked. Thanks @DavideBrex.